Equation of motion for a falling rotating cylinder (weight and Magnus force)
Similar question here, but unfortunately I have problems with the answer and does not help much.
If we have a cylinder (axis parallel to the ground) falling under gravity, that is given some constant angular velocity $ \omega $, then a lift force (the Magnus force) will be generated on the cylinder of magnitude $ F = kv $, where $ v $ is the speed of the cylinder and $ k $ depends on $ \omega $ and other constants. The direction for the Magnus force is given by the direction vector $ \hat{\mathbf{F}}_M = \hat{\boldsymbol{\omega}} \times \hat{\mathbf{v}} $.
The free-body diagram for a rotating cylinder in free fall is then:

I then tried to set up the equations of motion. Let $ \theta $ be the polar angle of the velocity vector, so that $ \mathbf{v} = (v \cos \theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} + (v \sin \theta) \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} $. For the above diagram, $ \theta $ will be negative. The Magnus force vector should then be
$$ \textbf{F}_M = kv \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta \\
\sin \theta \\
0 \end{bmatrix} = kv \begin{bmatrix}
-\sin \theta \\
\cos \theta \\
0 \end{bmatrix} = k \begin{bmatrix}
-v \sin \theta \\
v \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} = k \begin{bmatrix}
- \dot{y} \\
\dot{x} \end{bmatrix} = (-k \dot{y}) \hat{\boldsymbol{\imath}} + (k \dot{x}) \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} $$
The weight vector is $ \mathbf{W} = (-mg) \hat{\boldsymbol{\jmath}} $.
By Newton's second law, the equations from $ \mathbf{F}_M + \mathbf{W} = m \ddot{\mathbf{r}} $ that I get are
$$ m \ddot{x} = -k\dot{y}, \ \ m \ddot{y} = k\dot{x} - mg $$
Now, there are a few issues:

Since $ \dot{y} < 0 $ in free fall, there is an acceleration to the right. This is intuitively correct. However, it disagrees with the linked answer at the start, which gets the opposite sign (they use a clockwise rotation though!).

Solving the system with WolframAlpha (here), starting from rest, gives a solution with trigonometric functions in $ x(t) $ and $ y(t) $. This seems wrong, I doubt periodic motion would occur.


Can anyone check my equations? Have I made a mistake? Thanks for any help.

Well, if the direction of the Magnus force is $\mathbf F = \mathbf \omega\times \mathbf v$, then the linked answer that you mention is wrong. An easy sanity check is
$$
\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf v = (\mathbf \omega \times \mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf v = (\mathbf v\times \mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf \omega = 0
$$
This is true for your expressions, but for the expression Magnus force there $\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf v = 2kv_yv_x\neq 0$.

This system is relatively easy to solve if you know some calculus. Consider the system of equations in terms of velocities, for example:
$$
\begin{aligned}
m\dot v_x &= -kv_y\\
m\dot v_y &= kv_x -mg
\end{aligned}
$$
If you derive the second equation and use the first to substitute the $\dot v_x$, you get
$$
\ddot v_y = -\left (\frac km\right)^2 v_y
$$
This is the equation of the Harmonic Oscillator, whose solutions are given in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions, because they are oscillating solutions. By imposing that the initial velocity is zero, we get the solution $v_y = a \sin (\Omega t)$, with $\Omega = k/m$, and by the first equation, $v_x = a\cos(\Omega t)$. The amplitude is undetermined with only one initial condition, and we should consider the other initial condition ($x(0)=0$) to uniquely determine the solution.
If for some reason you missed some sign (which I don't believe) and the equations are wrong, for example let's suppose the right equations are
$$
\begin{aligned}
m\dot v_x &= kv_y\\
m\dot v_y &= kv_x -mg
\end{aligned}
$$
By doing the same procedure than before, we get
$$
\ddot v_y = \left (\frac km\right)^2v_y
$$
Which solutions are given by hyperbolic functions $\sinh$ and $\cosh$. Imposing the initial condition, $v_y = a\sinh(\Omega t)$ and $v_x = a\cosh(\Omega t)$. Now, this solutions are even more strange, because the particle will fall exponentially to the ground (what a fall!). This would represent a faster fall, which does not make sense since the Magnus force tends to decrease the vertical acceleration.
Your result is correct. Or at least, less insane.

I figured his answer wasn't quite right, but he managed to make a whole simulation out of it so it seemed foolish. But I've since made my own simulation incorporating other effects and it seems a lot more realistic. Thanks for the clear explanation!
